# How to invite everybody to a site in alfresco share site?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

In alfresco share site, we have the option to add a group to a site using add group. But how to invite every one to a site at a time. Right now the user has to add manually each users. I have 350 users, and the site creator will find it difficult to send invite to everyone by adding each person.

Comment: Invite a group, rather than people?

Comment: I cant invite group. In invite member option in site, I can search users only not any groups

Comment: I can add group but I cannot invite the members

Comment: If you put all the people in a group, and add that group to the site, does that not do what you need? (Especially as it skips some of the invite bits, just adds them)

Comment: Yes it works. But my requirement is that the people must have the freedom, whether to  join or decline the site. One more thing if I add a group to a site, the user don't get any notification that he is added to the site.

Comment: @Gagravarr I am stuck here. I got an idea to implement an email rule which send mail to everyone when a new site is created but I dont know how to send the site name and accept link in the mail

Comment: You may have to set outbound email properties
In global.properties file
you just have to only configure the email it will send automatically all the site invitation to members who has valid email id.